# swift my current time varibale isnt showing my actual current time

Tags: swift, nsdate

So here is my issue, when i try to find my current date and time, it gives me a time 7hrs ahead of my actual time. Example actual current time= 1pm, xcode current time 8pm. I would like to get the current time in the timezone of the user. any suggestions?

ok let me rephrase what Im asking. I have managed to convert the parsed endDate into a date. I know how to get the current date using NSDate, but it is NOT the right time. How can i change that time to the correct time? Please use a step by step plan, so i know how to handle this in the future. Thanks for all your input!

```
    // get end date
    let DateEnd = object.objectForKey("Ends") as! String
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    //dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm a"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(parseDateEnd)
    print(date)
    print(currentDate)
```

Comment: @ZoffDino it is not necessary to be true. If I were Niki, I would look for 'locale'

Comment: how would you solve this issue?

Comment: "I would like to get the current time in the timezone of the user". change your locale to reflect users locale

Comment: let formater = NSDateFormatter()
formater.locale = .....

Comment: i have added this "dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")" but this still doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: it is your users locale? it is the same as UTC

Comment: i am honestly so confused with the whole NSDate thing....I have tried so many different variations and not one seems to work

Comment: @NikkiRae don't use `print(currentDate)`, use `print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate))` instead

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` always store its data in UTC. Whatever timezone you want to convert to, you have to tell your `dateFormatter` to do that. Also, if you do `print(currentDate)`, it will always display time in UTC. You have to *format* it first.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm a"

let currentDate = NSDate()
print(currentDate) // 2015-11-13 22:02:09 +0000
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)) // 11/13/15, 05:02 PM
```

My timezone is EST (-05:00). My guess is you are in the -07:00 timezone.

---

**There's nothing wrong with your Swift or Xcode.** It's all about time in different timezones. As example, let's say it is:

- 9pm in Chicago (`UTC -05:00`)
- 2am in London  (`UTC +00:00`) ← this is what `NSDate()` would return
- 4am in Istanbul (`UTC +02:00`).

They represent the same moment in time, but different clock positions based on where you are. At this time of the year, UTC = GMT = London's time. If you are to call `NSDate()`, it will always return time in UTC, regardless of where you are. So you will get 2am.

To get your **local time**, you have to *format* it into your timezone. The default timezone for the `dateFormatter` is UTC. Hence, you must change that into your local timezone by:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
```

Comment: Because you have not **formatted** your date. See my edited answer

Comment: i did that it doesnt change anything the time is still wrong

Comment: @ZoffDino see the table below. it is still confusing ... compare Chicago and Istanbul :-) do you have an idea, what to do?

Comment: i have reworded my question

Comment: @ZoffDino let dict = NSTimeZone.abbreviationDictionary()
for i in -11...12 {
    let zone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: i*3600)
    for (key,_) in dict {
        let cz = NSTimeZone(name: key)
        if cz == zone {
            print(key)
        }
    }
}' sometimes it doesn't work ... in this case you can exactly set NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: i*3600)

Comment: @ZoffDino try this for (key,_) in dict {
    let tz = NSTimeZone(name: key)
    print(tz.debugDescription)
}

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .LongStyle
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
let currentDate = NSDate()
dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)

print(currentDate)
/*  prints your Zulu time with POSIX format

2015-11-14 01:48:30 +0000

*/

print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate))
/* prints your localized version
*  localized date and time with your time offset
*  as is preset in your computer

14/11/15 02:49:13 GMT+1

/*
```

....

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "")
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .LongStyle
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle

if let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-11-14 08:10:15 GMT-7") {
    print(dateFromString)

    // print
    // 2015-11-14 15:10:15 +0000
    //
    //
    // 2015-11-14 15:10:15 +0000 == 2015-11-14 08:10:15 GMT-7
    //
    //
}
```

to compare the dates

```
let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-11-14 08:10:15 GMT-7")
let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-11-14 15:10:15 +0000")
if let date1 = date1, let date2 = date2 {
    date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame // true !!!
}
```

.. time difference

```
let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-11-14 01:10:15 GMT-7")
let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-11-14 15:10:15 +0000")
if let date1 = date1, let date2 = date2 {
    date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame // false !
    date1.timeIntervalSince1970 - date2.timeIntervalSince1970 == -25200 // true
    date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2) == -25200 // true
    // the difference is in secons ( 7 hours * 3600 = 25200 seconds
}
```

... the same data, other form of time string, manually set time offset

```
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: -7*3600) // GMT-7
let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("01:10:15")

dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0*3600)  // GMT+0
let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("15:10:15")
if let date1 = date1, let date2 = date2 {
    date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame // false !
    date1.timeIntervalSince1970 - date2.timeIntervalSince1970 == -25200 // true
    date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2) == -25200 // true
    // the difference is in secons ( 7 hours * 3600 = 25200 seconds
}
```

... what is now the date1 and date2 ????

```
print(date1!) // 2000-01-01 08:10:15 +0000
print(date2!) // 2000-01-01 15:10:15 +0000
```

Comment: thanks but im still confused on whats going on and why i need to do all this

Comment: i have reworded my question

Comment: @NikkiRae it is still the same :-). try to explain your trouble. what the computer gives you vs what do you expect ...

Comment: it worked this time, however this gives me a string. I later on compare another it with another date. So the format needs to be in a date so i can use it. Is there a way i can now convert "dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)" to a date now? i tried just sending it back to datefromstring..but it didnt work

Comment: @NikkiRae NSDate() gives you approximately the same on all computers, yours, my, in Africa, USA, Japan. it is just one number, which can be presented in different formats.

Comment: yes i understand that, so how do i get my NSDate() to equal 7pm instead of 2am? It needs to be an NSDate format for me to compare it with another date

Comment: no way. but you can construct NSDate from string .... i give you an example soon :-)

Comment: i have already managed to construct an NSDate from String! Thats not the problem. So i f i cant do that, is it possible to compare two dates as strings?

Comment: @NikkiRae see my updated example. the same date are represented by different string. if you want to compare dates, compare NSDate s.

Comment: Ugh yes i know that i can only compare NSDates, but i want to compare the date and time where i am now (not gmt time in london) to an event in a list.

Comment: current means actual :-)

Comment: yes so i wanted to change that to my time and use it in the comparison

Comment: i dont want to compare the time in london to an event where i am

Comment: OK, if you compare now result of NSDate() with my NSDate() the numbers should be the same. event hough i am living on the opposite side  of the earth. if you give me your localized representation of 'now', i can compare it with my own. the string will be different. if i will make two NSDate objects, than the objects will be the same.

Comment: do you have the event list in string format? first use dateFromString and than compare to your NSdate(). you will see the difference .date1.compare(date2). the only important is, that you know the format of receiving string (from your event list)

Comment: yes i have a list in string format. I did that part in my code up top. so just for And i can compare two dates which i have also managed to do. Here is an example of whats happening when i run my compare... (Date1(2015-11-15, 2:30 pm)).compare(date2(2015-11-14, 4:50 Am)) Date 1 is date from event, Date2 is gmt time. I would like date2 to represent gmt for my location (2015-11-13, 9:50pm) What ive heard is this is not possible. Correct?

Comment: @NikkiRae time is not location specific. so 10:30 GMT in London and 10:30 GMT in Tokyo is exactly the same time. do you know the reference time offset for both dates which you compare? if this information is not included in your event list, you have to calculate it, or guess it, (based on location) so if my local time is10:30 GMT+1 and in the list is 10:30 GMT-7 (ot 03:30 GMT), i can calculate the time distance 10.5+1-10.5-7 = -8 hours (10.5+1-3.5+0=8)